# TransparencyKey Property on Forms

Tags: c#, forms, transparency

I would like to swith my form background transparency with Visual C# in a Windows Forms Application.

I used

```
BackColor = Color.White;
TransparencyKey = Color.White;
```

Now I want to switch back to "not transparent". How can I accomplish that? Just switching the BackColor makes the elements on the form look strange and it feels ugly.
I guess there is a way to reset the property.

Comment: What does 'ugly' mean?  Don't switch it back to Color.Fuchsia.  And don't use White as the transparency key.  Too common.  Use a fuchsed up color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing the previous values of BackColor and TransparencyKey in local variables, and restoring them when you want to revert to non-transparent?  For instance:

```
private Color _oldBG;
private Color _oldTPKey;

private void MakeTransparent() {
    _oldBG = BackColor;
    _oldTPKey = TransparencyKey;
    BackColor = Color.White;
    TransparencyKey = Color.White;
}

private void MakeNonTransparent() {
    BackColor = _oldBG;
    TransparencyKey = _oldTPKey;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

this is the original value:

```
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Empty;
```

You could set this, and then nothing will be transparent.

Comment: @vgoff: The original value is: _Color.Empty_

Comment: Hmm... then why set it?  I mean, if it is the original setting, then you would not have to set it again.  Just curious.  I guess you are saying to reset it, rather than set it?

Comment: Yes, this is some sort of resetting it.
(he said:)
"I want to switch back to "not transparent"."

Answer (score 0):

It's eleven years later, but I ran into this problem. So for any other readers: I set the transparency key mistakenly. A post from another forum said you could right click it, at design, and then reset it, but reset was disabled (grayed out). So I simply backspaced out the 'White' (in design) that was set. (I am confident it set it to 'Color.Empty' as one of the guys here noted.) Problem solved. I should say that I was using an ancient version of .net. Hopefully this will also work in more up to date versions.