# Unexpected transparency instead of white

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am working on a GUI , and it is showing Transparency for no reason in place of white color of the image itself , what might be the cause of this ?

Original GUI before executing application:

[image: Original GUI before executing application]

Upon Executing the Application:

[image: Upon Executing the Application]

Comment: Pretty sure WinForms designer just shows white even when some background is transparent. But in any case, without the design code there's no way for anyone to know the cause, screen shots are not sufficient.

Comment: Didn't you set `TransparencyKey` of your form to white?

Comment: @automatonhttp://i63.tinypic.com/apfo1e.png    , PayBill is the main form

Comment: @FarzinKanzi , umm , it is set to transparent , upon changing it to white , it shows same error!  , have a look at designer code : http://i63.tinypic.com/apfo1e.png

Comment: try `this.TransparencyKey = Color.Empty` instead of `this.TransparencyKey = Color.Transparent`

Comment: Your link is broken. But I suggest you to remove the TrancparencyKey and leave it blank.

Comment: @dlatikay this worked , please post this as an answer , so that I can close the question , thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this issue, reset the TransparencyKey back to its default value, or remove the assignment:

```
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Empty;
```

instead of

```
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Transparent;
```

References: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13426429/1132334, and [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When the TransparencyKey property is assigned a Color, the areas of the form that have the same BackColor will be displayed transparently